# Merge different data in response of 2-request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, kendo-grid

I created a `Service` in `angular` that request to services or `web-API` which have 2 `method` like:

```
query(state: any, url: string, param?: any): void {

    url = this.baseUrl + url;
    this.isBusy.value = true;
    this.fetch(url, state, param)
        .subscribe((x) => {
                this.isBusy.value = false;
                this.view = x;
            }
        );
}

fetch(url: string, state: any, param?: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    state.dontShowSnak = true;


    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (param != null) {
        params = params.append('param', param);
    }
    return this.http
        .post(url, state, {params: params})
        .map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
            data: response['result']['items'],
            total: parseInt(response['result']['totalCount'], 10)
        }));
}
```

This service is global and all of the application works with this.

Now! I have a page with 4 tab. when the page be started, first tab be loading, If I'll change tab and go to second tab(before get response of first tab), in the second tab, I'll have response or data of first tab. Why?

where is the problem?
the is problem in `kendo`? or my `service`?

- I work with `Kendo-grid`

But now I change my `service` and create 4 `separate` `service` for 4 tab, and I don't have this issue. all of the data is correct even if I'll change tab, before get response last tab.

Comment: I have added a solution w.r.t to shared service. Let me know if you need any clarification on that.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Thanks dude for helping, I read your answer.It looks right, let me to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) instead of `map` on `http.post()`. That will kill the ongoing request (initiated from tab1) and create a new `Observable` to be emitted for second tab. So that you now get data for the second tab only.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

fetch(url: string, state: any, param?: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    ......................
    return this.http
        .post(url, state, {params: params})
        .switchMap(response => { // using switchMap
            return Observable.of ({   
                data: response['result']['items'],
                total: parseInt(response['result']['totalCount'], 10)
            }) as Observable<GridDataResult>;
           }));
}
```

Comment: Glad that helped you! And I don't get your question w.r.t to session? It has no relation to `switchMap`.

Comment: Its ok! I was wrong about that question. Thanks. How to find you with email or something like that??

Comment: You can reach me on LinkedIn. Link provided in bio.

Comment: Thanks mean! I’ll find you.

Comment: Occured this error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

what is this??

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular 5, is it different??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179260/discussion-between-amit-chigadani-and-amirreza-farahlagha).